# How to track animation changes in monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, core-animation

I noticed that there is a method for capturing animation completion:

`UIView.SetAnimationDidStopSelector`

Is there also a way to get the changes during duration ?
I need to affect other objects according to the animation progress.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not.

Core Animation in native Cocoa Touch doesn't give you such callbacks so I would be very surprised if Mono Touch gave them to you.

Note that the actual value for the property changes to the end value right away. The animation happens on a separate layer (called the presentation layer)

Answer (score 0):

You can have updates and user interaction during an animation and I suppose that's what you're after here. For example:

```
UIView.Animate ( 0.5f, 0, UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, delegate { /* Animate things */}, delegate { /* Animation done */ } );
```

The option LayoutSubviews will update the subviews of your view during animation and you can influence the look of the view while it is being animated by overriding `LayoutSubviews()`.

AllowUserInteraction is kind of self explaining I presume.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i used a wired solution for this problem, what i did is i used a UIScrollView and changed it's values according to it's movement in that way i also get the velocity effect:  _hideenScroller = new UIScrollView(_frame);
  AddSubview(_hideenScroller);
  _hideenScroller.Scrolled+=delegate
  {
   //track the changes here....
  };